# c# invalid win32 application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, 32-bit

Okay so I've read about, tried fair few solutions but still haven't managed to resolve this problem.

My application when testing on a 32bit machine (I've only tested on 1) instantly crashes on startup with invalid 32 application and no other error messages or information for guidance.

The application is a c# .NET 4.5.2; built in visual studio 2017. I've set it to X86 in the build configuration and the application runs on my 64bit development machine.

For test purposes I made a 32bit windows 7 virtual machine, built the solution and copied everything in the output bin folder to this virtual 32bit windows 7 machine. It runs fine, as expected. However, if I copy that exact folder to the physical 32bit machine, it crashes saying invalid 32bit application.

I even put a condition in to check the IntPtr.Size is 4, to assure my application is running in 32bit.

That made me think maybe a resource is built in 64bit, but if thats the case why would it run in the 32bit virtual environment. O.o

I'm going to try and find another physical 32 bit machine to test on.

Any guidance on how I can troubleshoot, or retrieve more information on the error would be great.

The physical machine has dot net 4.5.2 installed and 99.99% sure vcredist_x86 is also installed.

Comment: Did you reference some external assembly or dll built for x64?

Comment: I've referenced a fair few external assemblys, far as I'm aware they are 32bit, or at least should be. The build works in a 32bit virtual environment (vmware) which makes me think it's not this though

Comment: For those that are flagging this as an off topic post, stop. This as identified correctly compiler pulling in a 64 bit image which causes a problem on a 32 bit machine or corruption

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why my question has been negative points... But this has now been resolved.

The problem was that Team-viewer was corrupting the files somehow while transferring them. I tried to transfer the files zipped and noticed that the zip was strangely small and not opening. So I went into the office and did the swap by USB and BAM. Working. Annoying or what.